# Electrical wiring question - interconnect question

Tags: electrical

i have three ventilation fans on three different circuits that are connected to a switch in each bathroom.  (One fan/bathroom)

The fans are all connected to exhaust ducts that terminates into a shared duct for my building.

I would like to put an electronic damper at the end of my duct that is opened when any one (or two or three) of the three ventilation fans are on.

Is there an electronic device that I can connect all three circuits to and it will then only pass 120v ac or 12v doc out when one or more switches are on?

Comment: Why do you need an electronic damper, why isn't a mechanical damper sufficient?

Comment: that could work. How ever I have one room that does not have a fan hooked up, ie the airflow through the vent is driven by rooftop exhaust fan. I didn't want to complicate the question. For that one, I would connect the light switch to the device that controlled the electrical damper.

Answer (score 1):

There may be other ways, but I'd use simple relay logic.

Three separate relays, switched contacts wired in parallel, connected to power for damper and damper.

Each relay has a coil that controls the relay - those are connected (individually - one relay coil per circuit) to the switched circuits.

Any one circuit being on will open the damper. Two or three circuits on will leave the damper open. When the last circuit is shut down, the damper closes.